# Brushless ESC Recommendations

Tags: motor, arduino-due, robotics, pid

I've got a project in which I'll be controlling 8 24V/10A brushless DC motors with an Arduino Due on a quadrupedal robot. I've been having trouble finding ESCs that would work well for this application and was wondering if anyone could provide recommendations. My ideal ESC would be one with on-board PID control given an encoder. In looking around, I've only been able to find one [ESC with this capability](https://www.embention.com/product/motor-controller/) but lacked the power output these motors want.

A secondary question would be if it's reasonable to run 8 PID loops on the Due alongside its other tasks (primarily serial data receiving/transmitting). I feel like it might be too much for the Due to handle, but I wanted to get other's opinions on this.

Sidenote: I have enough of a gear reduction between motor and output shaft that fine movements should not be an issue.